# Change python version running the Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I installed Spyder when I had python 2.7, now I have newer versions of python, e.g., python 3.5. I tried to install 'seaborn' package, which is installed successfully, but apparently, for python 3.5. Therefore, the package is not recognized in Spyder where uses python 2 as the interpreter. Changing the interpreter in the setting does not work.

Does anybody know how to change python version in Spyder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pip2 install seaborn
```

or

```
pip2.7 install seaborn
```

this should install seaborn for the python 2.7 interpreter.